# How to upload a Registry CAR file to ESB WSO2?

Tags: wso2, registry, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I've created a Registry Resources Project on Developer Studio (WSO2) with my WSDLs, transformations and XSDs.

I'd like to upload the .CAR file (exported by this Registry Resources Project) on my ESB Registry. How can I do it?

I'm not using Governance Registry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the registry role to the "EnterpriseServiceBus". You can change the serve role by editing the POM file of the Carbon Application.

Open the pom.xml file of the C-App project with "Carbon Application Pom Editor". If you haven't installed Eclipse M2E in your Eclipse, pom.xml will open by default with that editor. Otherwise use "Open With" option and select the "Carbon Application Pom Editor".
You will see the set of C-App artifacts in your workspace in this editor and you will see the Server Role field in the editor.
Expand the name of the Registry Resource Editor and click on the drop down list in Server Role and select EnterpriseServiceBus from the list.
Save the Editor and Export the C-App and generate the CAR file.

Answer (score 1):

The registry resources project and the ESB Config project should be bundled together in one Composite Application Project. Then the .car file is exported on your hard drive, anywhere you find appropriate. Then, opening the console management in the Browser, find Carbon Application -> Add, select your .car file and click on Upload.

Refresh the Carbon Application->List page until you see your project. If, by any chance, it is faulty, you would see a red sentence - you can click on it, see the error messages (part of them, at least) and remove it.

[Here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Creating+and+Deploying+a+Carbon+Application) you can see a short explanation about uploading the .car file into your ESB.

[image: RegistryResources]

When you click on the Application from the Carbon Applications list, you can see whether there are any registry resources uploaded as well:

[image: capp list]

Comment: I've bundled Registry Resources Project and ESB Config Project together in one Composite Application Project, but it doesn't works. When I upload this .CAR on my ESB, Registry Resources Project files are not being uploaded to ESB Registry.

Comment: When you make the project, do you see the resources in the Registry Resources project? I am uploading a picture to my answer. Also, you can find them in the ESB console by going to Registry (at the bottom) -> Browse -> system -> config -> myresources. Do you see them there?

Comment: In my Registry Resources Project I can see my resources. I have 2 projects on my Developer Studio: one for ESB, and another for Registry. I tried to create one CAR with both projects but when I upload this on ESB, registry resources doesn't appears on ESB registry

Comment: But do you see them in the Composite Application Project in Eclipse? Do you see them when you click on the application in the browser? 
Is there any information in the wso2-esb-errors.log? (found in the esb home folder -> repository -> logs).

Comment: PS. You can also try opening the .car file with some archive extractor to see whether the resources are inside.

Comment: When I open my .CAR file with a archive extractor, I can see all my Registry Project Resources (WDSLs, XSD, endpoints) and my ESB Project Resources (proxies and sequences).

Comment: But if I open on ESB (like your second picture) my resources doesn't appears. I can see just my proxy and my sequences.

Comment: That's strange. Are there any error messages in the log?

Answer (score -1):

Hope [1] will help you. It consists all the steps need for develop and deploy registry resources to esb using wso2 developer studio.

First create a registry resource project in developer studio and add your registry resources. Save your registry resource project and create a new composite application project. Add your previous registry resource project to it as a dependency along with your other esb artifact, connector exporter projects.

Make sure to change the registry role to the “EnterpriseServiceBus”. You can change the serve role by editing the POM file of the Carbon Application

Save the Editor and Export the C-App and generate the CAR file. Then you can upload the CAR file to your esb server instance.

[1] https://dushaniwellappili.wordpress.com/2016/12/01/develop-and-deploy-registry-resources-to-esb-using-wso2-developer-studio/

Comment: @geisterfurz007  have edited my answer. Please have a look